# Showing mouse event in blender info panel

Tags: python

It is interesting to see that the api for all operations happening in blender is shown in the info panel. Is it possible to show the mouse operations also, such as stocking with mouse during texturing painting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally i could find that there is an option in blender called "debug_wm" which can be enabled by typing

```
bpy.app.debug_wm=True
```

in the python console which lets you see the those function calls linked to the mouse. Make sure that you launch blender from the terminal as the logs are written to the terminal on which blender is opened.